# Copy/duplicate an item in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have this SharePoint list with about 30 columns. Sometimes I have to add items that share the same values for many fields. As this is quite time-consuming, I am wondering if it is possible to make a duplicate of an item (or if there is any off-the-shelf product that can do this). This way, I could simply edit the duplicate to change the few fields that are different, sparing me a lot of time.

Please note that using the "edit in datasheet" mode is, unfortunately, not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way:

- Created a new column in which the users type the ID of an existing item in the list
- Using a custom SharePoint Designer workflow, a predefined set of values are copied from the existing item to the new item